# How to reverse a string in bash script?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a string like that:

```
|abcdefg|
```

and I want to reverse this String

```
gfedcba
```

Is that possible in bash?

Comment: Of course it's possible to reverse a string but what happened to `|` characters?

Comment: I want a Full String to divide in a Characters such as abcde   a b c d e

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, you posted a string, then a different string that is *not* reversed original string.

Comment: in simple words how we reverse a String in Bash.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-string-shell-programming/, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11461625, https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-reverse-a-text-string-on-the-Unix-command-line and finally https://bfy.tw/Qing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `rev` command you can reverse the string:

```
$ echo '|abcdefg|' |rev
|gfedcba|
```

if you want pure bash solution:

```
str='|abcdefg|'; for ((i=${#str}-1; i>=0; i--));do printf "${str:$i:1}"; done
```

- `${#str}` returns the character length of its parameter *`str`*.
- `${str:start:length}` picks *length* characters from its parameter *`str`* from *`start`* point (the first character has index 0).

if you don't want first & last pipe characters, do:

```
str='|abcdefg|'; for ((i=${#str}-2; i>=1; i--));do printf "${str:$i:1}"; done
```